# How to use recursive template?

Tags: meteor

I don't know how to deal with recursive array in template.and I can't find anything in handlebarsjs's docs

there are my codes:
js:

```
    var branch = [{
                name:"firstLayerNodeA",
                has_branch:true,
                branch:[{
                        name:"secondLayoutNodeA",
                        has_branch:false
                    },{
                        name:"secondLayoutNodeB",
                        has_branch:true,
                        branch:[{
                                name:"thirdLayerNodeA",
                                has_branch:true,
                                branch:[{
                                        //fourth Layer
                                        //fifth Layer
                                        //.....
                                }]
                        }]
                }]
            },{
                name:"firstLayerNodeB",
                has_branch:false
            }]
```

html

> ```
> <Template name="tree">
>   <ul>
>   {{#each brach}}
>       <li>
>         name
>         {{#if has_branch}}
>           <ul>
>           {{#each brach}}
>               <li>
>                 name
>                 {{#if has_brach}}
>                       {{#each brach}}
>                           .....third layer
>                           .....fourth layer
>                           ....
>                       {{/each}}
>                 {{/if}}
>               </li>
>           {{/each}
>           </ul>
>         {{/if}}
>       </li>
>   {{/each}}
>   </ul>
> </Template>
> ```

There are good ideas that deal with branch in template?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use nested templates:

**client side js**

```
Template.tree.branch = function() {
    var branch = ...
    return branch;
}
```

**Html**

```
<template name="tree">
  <ul>
    {{#each branch}}
      <li>    
        {{>branch}}
      </li>       
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>

<template name="branch">
    {{name}}
    {{#if branch.length}}
       <ul>
           {{#each branch}}
               <li>
                   {{>branch}}
               </li>
           {{/each}}
       </ul>
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

Also you don't really need `has_branch`. Just check the length of the branch array instead as each will only loop if its an array and theres stuff in there

Answer (score 2):

[Akshat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15295326/1870254) is very good.
However, using it I had some problems with the event handling. The event was catched several times; once for every instances of the `branch` template that contained the element throwing the event.

Not sure whether this is a bug or a feature...anyway I could overcome it using:

```
Template.branch.events({
  'click': function (e,b) {    
    console.log("this will show up as often as deep your tree is");
    if (this._id==b.data._id)
      console.log("this will show up only once");
  }
});
```

Comment: You can prevent this by using e.stopPropagation()

Comment: I think that did not work or not as expected back when I wrote the answer...@ivan133 did you actually test if does now?